# How to apply bootstrap classes for pages in magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4.3

I had created a page with bootstrap classes but those styles are not applying for ref please find the below URL.

https://icontiles.co.uk/delivery-status

please find the below code also

> ```
> <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-5">
> <thead>
> <tr>
> <th scope="col">#</th>
> <th scope="col">First</th>
> <th scope="col">Last</th>
> <th scope="col">Handle</th>
> </tr>
> </thead>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <th scope="row">1</th>
> <td>Mark</td>
> <td>Otto</td>
> <td>@mdo</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
> <th scope="row">2</th>
> <td>Jacob</td>
> <td>Thornton</td>
> <td>@fat</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
> <th scope="row">3</th>
> <td>Larry</td>
> <td>the Bird</td>
> <td>@twitter</td>
> </tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

here the problem is these styles are not applying table-bordered table-striped

Answer (score 1):

For adding Bootstrap 4 In Magento(tested) & in your custom theme, follow the below steps:

1. Bootstrap CSS files inside the web folder

Note:

> THEME_LOCATION => app\design\frontend\vendor-name\theme-name\ Call
> bootstrap css files in default_head_blocks
> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml

Adding css

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!--Bootstrap css-->
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

2. Adding Js files in bundle form rather than individual because the individual doesn't work
   Place bootstrap.bundle.js files can download from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\web\js\bootstrap.bundle.js Call Bootstrap
> Js Into requirejs-config.js
> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\requirejs-config.js

code for

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle',
    } ,
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Add below code in header.phtml after your already present script tag

> THEME_LOCATION\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml

Code: `<script type="text/javascript">require(['bootstrap']);</script>`

Run Below Commands:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

(Append -f if you are using Magento 2.2.x >= version)

> php bin/magento cache:flush